# Kotlin suspend function in Reactive Data Repositores return null

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I am facing a "problem" with mongo reactive repositories. I am trying to use kotlin's coroutines and instead of writing fun declaration like this:

```
fun findEntityById(id: String) : Mono<Entity>
```

I wrote a suspend function like this :

```
suspend fun findEntityById(id: String) : Entity
```

But when I test the function with an id that does not exist, instead of getting an DataAccessException(what I anticipated), I am getting null.
Is there a way to "fix" this or get around. For now I only thought of something like this

```
suspend fun findEntityById(id: String) : Entity = findEntityById(id).awaitSingleOrNull() ?: throw EmptyResultDataAccessException()
```

Maybe there is  a better solution and someone has faced the same "problem" that I have(or maybe I am doing something wrong), i'd be glad to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Can you file a bug report in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/?

Comment: @mp911de, you mean make an issue on git?

Comment: It seems it doesn't work this way. You have to use Mono and then call one of await methods.

Comment: @breedish, it does work this way( Throws EmptyResultDataAccessException) when used with r2dbc. This problem occurred to me when I used mongo reactive repositories.